# Lua - Audio.stop() not working properly

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have a big problem with audio.stop()
when I call it , the next audio gets call
I want to stop all audios before changing scene
but its not working the next audio starts playing in the next scene.
here is my code so I can explain better.

here I start the first audio file.

```
function scene:show( event )
    local sceneGroup = self.view
    local phase = event.phase
    if phase == "will" then 
        narrativeChannel = audio.play( audio1, { channel=5, onComplete=NarrationStart } )
    elseif phase == "did" then

    end
end

NarrationStart = function (  )
        narrativeTimer = timer.performWithDelay( 100,function (  )
            catBubble.isVisible = true
            catText.isVisible = true
            transition.from(catText, {time = 400,alpha = 0,y = catText.y - 15, onComplete = function ()
        narrativeChannel = audio.play( audio2, { channel=5}) end })
end, 1 )
```

and here is where I stop it

```
function scene:hide( event )
    local sceneGroup = self.view

    local phase = event.phase

    if event.phase == "will" then
        if(narrativeChannel ~= nil) then
            audio.stop( ) 
            print("stoped") --gets call
        end
        transition.cancel()
        if(narrativeTimer ~= nil)then timer.cancel( narrativeTimer ) end 
    elseif phase == "did" then
        -- Called when the scene is now off screen
    end 

end
```

when I change scene while the first audio1 is play, the first audio gets stoped but right after that the audio2 start...
I dont know why is that happening.
please any ideas or coments how to fix this.
I tried audio.stop() , audio.stop(channelUsed)
and nothing keeps playing the next audio I dont want that.

thanks in advance.

Info: scene Manager: Composer
Corona build : Version 2014.2463 (2014.10.14)

Comment: See `transition.from(catText, {time = 400,alpha = 0,y = catText.y - 15, onComplete = function () narrativeChannel = audio.play( audio2, {channel=5}) end })` I think `transition.cancel()` would not stop `onComplete` function, you can print something on `onComplete` function, OK?

Answer (score 0):

Albert is right, the `transition.cancel()` does indeed not cancel `onComplete`.

You could add a varable like `isAudioOn` and put it to false when you stop the audio. That way you can check for that variable inside your `onComplete` as such.

```
NarrationStart = function (  )
        if(isAudioOn) then
            narrativeTimer = timer.performWithDelay( 100,function (  )
            catBubble.isVisible = true
            catText.isVisible = true
            transition.from(catText, {time = 400,alpha = 0,y = catText.y - 15, onComplete = function () narrativeChannel = audio.play( audio2, { channel=5}) end })
        end
end, 1 )
```

Comment: thanks! I did not know that.
that will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting `audio.stop(narrativeChannel)` ? And maybe putting them in a different channel is good way to isolate the problem.